# Further Improve MySql Query Results Ordering

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have a query that operates primarily on a full text indexed field.

The query is as follows:

```
SELECT
    MATCH (g.GameTitle) AGAINST ('quake ii') as Score,
    g.*, p.id AS platformid,
    p.alias AS PlatformAlias,
    p. name,
    p.icon
FROM
    games as g,
    platforms as p
WHERE
    MATCH (g.GameTitle) AGAINST ('quake ii')
    AND g.Platform = p.id;
```

I would expect mysql to return all results closest to the search string "quake ii" towards the top, however this is not the case... in fact, there are two entries in the DB with a game title of "quake ii" and these are separated on either end of the score ordering even though they have the same score.

This can be seen in the results here:

```
Score               id      GameTitle
-----               --      ---------
5.883631706237793   393     Quake II
5.883631706237793   777     Quake
5.883631706237793   778     Quake 4
5.883631706237793   2922    Quake
5.883631706237793   2924    Quake II
5.817491054534912   427     Quake III Arena
5.817491054534912   2925    Quake III Arena
5.689572811126709   85      Enemy Territory: Quake Wars
```

How could I get the desired results of both "quake ii" entries to appear at the top of the results??

Answer (score 0):

From:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html

> The minimum and maximum lengths of words to be indexed are defined by the ft_min_word_len and ft_max_word_len system variables. .... The default minimum value is four characters;

So the 'ii' is actully completely ignored in the search.

That page also details how to change the minimum

Answer (score 0):

you could always add order by...

```
ORDER BY
   case when  left( g.GameTitle, 8 ) = "Quake II" and length( trim( g.GameTitle )) = 8
      then 1 else 2 end
```

This would flush the same Quake II (by same length too) to the top, and all others under it...